# one line with multiple color text in phpword?

Tags: php, phpword

Is there any method to write different color of text in a same line like this but it change whole line color?

I want my line to like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
$section->addText( 'Headline: ', (array('color'=>'#70AD47')),$fontStyleIndexPara);
            $section->addText(cleanstring($data[$k]['ArticleTitle']),$fontStyleIndexPara);
           `
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing the individual text parts directly into the section with addText(), enclose it with addTextRun().

By using addTextRun() you can prevent the line break.

Code for your example:

```
$TextRun = $section->addTextRun();
$TextRun->addText( 'Headline: ', array('color'=>'70AD47'));
$TextRun->addText(cleanstring($data[$k]['ArticleTitle']));
```

The # is not used for the color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use something like that:

```
$sentence='Your text in this sentence the two first word will get the stylefont while the rest will get the stylefont2';
$word_arr=explode(' ', $sentence);

$phpWord->addParagraphStyle('p3Style',array('align'=>'center'));
$c = 0;
$textrun = $section->addTextRun(array('align' => 'center'));
for($i = 0; $i < count($word_arr); $i++)
{
    $c++;
    if($c < 2)
    {
        $textrun->addText($word_arr[$i].' ', $styleFont);
    }
    else
    {
        $textrun->addText($word_arr[$i].' ', $styleFont2);
    }
}
```